# Google Directory API : manage invitation and request to join

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Is there an API that lets an application send invitations and requests to join a group?

I have checked the Google Directory API at https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/, but all I can find is the members API that lets an application directly add members.

What I am looking for is :
- to send a request to join a group,
- to list, accept or reject such requests,
- to send an invitation to join a group,
- to list, accept or reject such invitation.

I had no luck checking the reference, a google search and a search on stack overflow also turned out nothing. Does anyone know if such an API even exist, and if so, where can I find the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there seems to be no ad-hoc API method for that. The currently supported group operations can be found in [Directory API: Group Members](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-group-members#create_member) namely: add member, update group membership, retrieve a group member, retrieve all group member and delete member. You'd have to implement the other functionalities you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's what I thought but I was looking for a way to share invitations with the Google admin console. My users will have to do without.